# Survey Validation

Tags: validation, survey

I have some validation set to a name column to ensure that the name field begins with a capital:

```
=(CODE(MID([First Name],1,1))>64)
+(CODE(MID([First Name],1,1))>91)
=2
```

This isn't prompting the user to input an uppercase letter as the first character, it allows them to submit and save the lowercase value.

Is there something wrong with the validation code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
=(CODE(MID([First Name],1,1))>64)
+(CODE(MID([First Name],1,1))>91)
=2
```

is kinda dirty, you are relying on booleans to count as 1 (luckily for you SP is forgiving).. but your second comparison is wrong... should be <

What about:

```
=AND(  CODE(MID([First Name],1,1))>64 , CODE(MID([First Name],1,1))<91  )
```

A readable and fexibele approach would be:

```
=FIND( LEFT([First Name]) , "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" )
```

*LEFT second parameter defaults to 1, and since SharePoint is relaxed about boolean values, any FIND>0 is TRUE*

see https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what above code is doing.. but you can always add a content editor web part on the form and add the jquery file and below code to validate if the text box contain strings in upper case letter

```
var upperCase= new RegExp('[A-Z]');
if($(this).val().match(upperCase))
{
    $("#passwordErrorMsg").html("OK");

}
else
{
return false;
}
```